# Minecraft launcher refuses to launch game in Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: minecraft

I have played with Minecraft and the launcher has worked before but every time I try, I get a launcher log output given by:

```
[17:25:34 ERROR]: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
[17:25:34 ERROR]: Game ended with bad state (exit code 1)
[17:25:34 INFO]: Ignoring visibility rule and showing launcher due to a game crash
[17:25:34 INFO]: Deleting /home/porter/.minecraft/versions/1.12.2/1.12.2-natives-551255038095
```

The game output also says:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release
Error: Could not find or load main class net.minecraft.client.main.Main
```

Comment: Me too on 16.10 and on my Mom's Mint box. It might not even be limited to Linux users. Haven't found a fix yet, though.

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 17.07. Did you mean 17.04 or 17.10? While I doubt the version actually matters, it would be nice to get it right.

Comment: 17.04 is the appropriate version sorry for the mix up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to just play, go to Edit Profile on the launch screen, and check **Enable experimental development versions ("Snapshots")**, **Save Profile**, and make sure that the use version **Use Latest Version** is selected in the drop down.

You will be able to play at least, even if it's not the latest stable.

This is a known issue, read more about it here: https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-121292

Comment: so it only affects  the latest version, thanks for the bug fix

Answer (score 0):

the minecraft launcher has a bug that sometimes won't run the latest version of minecraft, to fix this, simply go to edit profile and check the box labeled **ENABLE EXPERIMENTAL DEVELOPMENT VERSIONS ("SNAPSHOTS")**save your profile and make sure you are using **USE LATEST VERSION**in the version box. But if you're planning on playing servers, don't use snapshots, simply backstep one release.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because you downloaded other versions of openjdk.
I fixed it by going into "Edit Profile" and check the checkbox next to "Java executable" (if it isn't checked already") and make sure you are using the right version of openjdk "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java" save it and now it is working again.